# Study materials for cardinals and ω_1 / continuum hypothesis

Tags: reference-request, cardinals

What textbook (chapter) can I read to understand cardinality concepts like $\omega_1$, $\aleph_1$, and the continuum hypothesis?

The text I'm currently trying to read also uses phrases like "let $\kappa$ be a cardinal such that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$", which I would like to understand. I'm assuming this is the same general topic?

I see a lot of references to topology on the [Wikipedia page for $\omega_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal); are these concepts covered in a typical introductory topology textbook though? Can I study this without topology?

Comment: What's your current background?

Comment: @RobertShore I have working knowledge of logic, category theory, and computability theory. I also seem to have picked up basic topology because I needed it for some adjacent material (e.g. I know what a basis or a continuous function in topology is), but so far I have successfully avoided taking a proper topology course.  Think graduate-level math/compsci in general.

Comment: What is the text you're reading? (And this is really a topic in set theory, not topology - in my experience all you'll see in a topology text like Munkres about $\omega_1$ is its uncountability, well-orderedness, and regularity. So I'd look for a set theory text, not a topology one.)

Comment: I think set theory might be an excellent pointer actually. Do you want to copy this into an answer so I can accept it? As for materials, I found an [An Introduction To Set Theory](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/Set_Theory.pdf) by William Weiss, which in chapter 7 (Cardinality) seems to cover all the concepts and syntax in my question. It's freely available too.